# How do I handle accepted multiplayer invites with Game Center's Fast Start in iOS?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

I'm trying to implement the following Fast Start code shown during WWDC 2021 .

```
// Set the GKMatch delegate and present your game scene when didFindMatch is called
func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let gameVC = GameSceneViewController()
    gameVC.match = match
    match.delegate = gameVC
    self.present(gameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, I'm receiving the error "Cannot find 'GameSceneViewController()' in scope" when I try to build it. Looking for documentation on it, it doesn't seem like GameSceneViewController() is a callable method either. Is there supposed to be a class with a constructor? If so, how would I tie the GameScene to a ViewController?

Comment: Where are you writing code?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 13